# webpage takes a lot of time to load

Tags: java, javascript, android

In a webview in Android, I first load a webpage and then display only a part of it using some javascript commands. During the whole process a "loading" message is displayed.

Problem : It take s alot of time to load even if the internet speed is fast. (>60 sec always). How to reduce time ?

This is my WebViewClient class that I attach with the webview (and the class contains only 1 method):

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0].innerHTML=''");
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('gbh')[0].innerHTML=''");
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].innerHTML=''");
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('card_title')[0].innerHTML=''");
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('cell_input')[0].innerHTML=''");
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('pre')[0].innerHTML=''");
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML=''");
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('foot')[0].innerHTML=''");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir, You could use the YSlow or Google PageLoad plugins for your browser, to get specific tips on how to improve page load and speed up your page.

By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, it does not enable JavaScript and also web page errors are ignored.